# javascript convert <string, string[]> to <string, string>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object with key/value pairs where the value is an array of strings:

```
var errors = {
    "Message": ["Error #1", "Error #2"],
    "Email": ["Error #3", "Error #4"]
};
```

I would like to convert this to a key/value pair with the first element of each array so that it is a  instead of :

```
var firstErrorOnly = {
    "Message": "Error #1",
    "Email": "Error #3"
};
```

I tried doing this using `jQuery.map` but I was not getting the results I wanted. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You should post the code you tried that didn't work.

Comment: doesn't even need `jQuery.map`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can traverse the whole object using [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to create a new object in the style you wish.

```
var firstErrorOnly = {};
for( var key in errors ) {
  if ( errors.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
    firstErrorOnly[ key ] = errors[key][0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a jQuery implementation, try this:

```
var firstErrorOnly = {};
$.each(errors, function(i, value) {
    firstErrorOnly[i] = value[0];
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kwdEf/)